# Is it possible somehow to run old red hat 8.0 32bit inside debian 4.0 64bit (virtualization)?

Tags: linux, debian, virtualization, redhat, physical-to-virtual

So I've got this disk image file of a failing server that I'd like to run inside much newer box. Since I cannot dedicate this new machine I'm thinking virtualization. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

You can do it with xen, kvm or even openbox. Maybe you will have to deal with boot issues or even mount the old image and `cp` it to the new one, but it is possible. What you are trying to do is "physical to virtual" or "p2v". Google it and you will se various cases, [like this one](http://www.windley.com/archives/2007/08/p2v_how_to_make_a_physical_linux_box_into_a_virtual_machine.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I've done this specifically with RedHat 8.0 using VMWare Server 1.0 and 2.0 products, but any virtualization solution should work. You'll want to check a few P2V (Physical to Virtual) techniques to see what will work best for the source system, though. A couple of quick links:

http://boink.pbworks.com/w/page/7045897/LinuxP2V

http://conshell.net/wiki/index.php/Linux_P2V